# Проблема с кодировкой MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, utf-8

сайт написанный на PHP база данных - MYSQL в кодировке utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode (utf8_bin), все файлы сайта в - UTF-8.
при записе в базу запросами SQL в таблице записывается кракозябры (непонятно что в неправильной кодировке)
пробывал записать напрямую в базу нормальный рос. текст, но читает все равно знаки вопроса типу "????? ?????????? ??????"

Может кто то подсказать в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно бывает полезно сразу же после того как установили соедиение с сервером MySQL указать в какой кодировке будет работа. Используется запрос

```
SET NAMES UTF-8
```

А уже после этого можно читать и писать в базу.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: Предпочтительный способ сделать это: mysqli_set_charset(), а в PDO указать чарсет в конструкторе. http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset

Answer (score 0):

я решил это так (может кому нибудь пригодиться):

```
    if(array_search($db_type,PDO::getAvailableDrivers())!== false) {
        $connect_dsn = $db_type . ":host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $database . ";charset=utf8";
        $connect_opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        );

        $this->CONNECTION = new PDO($connect_dsn, $user, $password, $connect_opt);

    }
```